# APKs with identical release keystores

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

Is there a risk if I release an apk in Google Play with my release keystore and someone else release the same app with the same release keystore from another account.

An outsorcing company is developing an app for me and I want to publish it from my account, but I`m not sure if they can harm the already published app if they have the keystore, and not my Google account.

What are my options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware it doesn't matter if more than one app uses the same keystore, however, if someone manages to find it, they can then use it to deploy dodgey versions of your app onto the market.

You can't howver, have two versions of the same app uploaded to the play store unless you change the package name within the AndroidManifest file.